# A short word riddle

Tags: word

You won't see me in the darkest night,
but you can see me when the sun shines bright.
You can see me in the water, but I'll never get wet.
Sometimes I am slim and sometimes I am fat.

Who am I?

Hint

> I can be more than 50 shades of grey ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be

> Reflection

Explanation follows

You won't see me in the darkest night,

> No reflection in dark

but you can see me when the sun shines bright.

> reflection will be present when the sun is bright or when there is sufficient light

You can see me in the water, but I'll never get wet.

> We can see the reflection in water but it will never get wet.

Sometimes I am slim and sometimes I am fat.

> reflection will be thin or think based on the distance of object from reflecting plane.

**First Guess**

Are you a

> Shadow

Explanation follows

You won't see me in the darkest night,

> No shadow in dark

but you can see me when the sun shines bright.

> Shadow will be present when the sun is bright

You can see me in the water, but I'll never get wet.

> We can see shadow in water but it will never get wet.

Sometimes I am slim and sometimes I am fat.

> Shadow will be thin or think based on the distance of light source.

Comment: Oof, answered at literally exact same time!

Comment: After I pressed the submit, I saw 2 answers. :D

Comment: It is a very close answer and would also fit to the riddle. But it is not the word I am looking for :)

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> A reflection?
>  You can't be seen in the dark, only when there's light to see by; images can be reflected in water, and funhouse mirrors can drastically distort a reflection's sizes.

Comment: That is the correct answer!

Answer (score 1):

Is this yet another riddle with the answer

> Shadow? Can’t see at night, can’t get wet, can be all different shapes and sizes

Comment: it is close, but it's not the answer :)